Client not receiving notifications in specified channel (Expo, Android)
I have already specified the notification channel in my backend code, but somehow the client doesn't receive the notification in the specified channel. I also set the notification channel for the client. I already followed the doc, but the notifications are received as Miscellaneous, as mentioned in the documentation on handling-notification-channels.
This the snippet of my code:
Backend
for (let pushToken of savedPushTokens) {
    if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken)) {
      console.error(`Push token ${pushToken} is not a valid Expo push token`);
      continue;
    }

    notifications.push({
      to: pushToken,
      sound: "default",
      title: title,
      body: body,
      data: data,
      sound: "default",
      priority: "high",
      channelId: "test",
    });
  }

Client/mobile
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("test", {
        name: "Test",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        sound: true,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }

    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      // Learn more about projectId:
      // https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#configure-projectid
      token = (
        await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
          projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
        })
      ).data;
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    return token;
  }

What did I miss here?

There can be multiple reasons for this mismatch in Channel IDs, notification priority, version compatibility.

I have the exact same issue. It seems that push API always send message to a default channel named Miscellaneous.
Even if I use this tool https://expo.dev/notifications and set a channel id  to 'test' for example, the message is still send to Miscellaneous channel
